# When you store data into a VARCHAR in mysql does it take into account returns? or does it just store a block of text?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm storing text for a blog article using VARCHAR and I was wondering if it will take into account the returns in the text or just store the information as a big blob of text?

side note:
I'm not using a WYSIWYG because I don't want the blog users to be able to style their articles.

Comment: FYI: **return** = **newline** and in code that is `\n`; to answer yes it will still store the `\n`

Comment: FYI2: sometimes, returns are "\r\n". Just trying to provide complete info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, a 'return' is still a new line character, so will be stored. 
It's essentially stored as a \n (a new line)

If you're storing large chunks of text though, you should look to using something like the 'TEXT' or 'BLOB' formats, rather than VARCHAR

For more information on those types, see the docs: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blob.html

Comment: Well if it's purely text based, then sure, TEXT is the way to go, just providing both options to give OP more options

Comment: Since MySQL 5.0.3, there's little point in using `TEXT` since `VARCHAR` can hold up to the same 64KiB.  If one needs more than that, consider `MEDIUMTEXT` (up to 16MiB) or `LONGTEXT` (up to 4GiB).

Comment: If you're not noticing the newlines showing up when you output the text, use PHP's `nl2br($text)` to convert those newlines stored in the database.